# Python gmail imap - How to read mail and print it as the original headers

Tags: python

**I have a script that reads mail from the Gmail box and then prints it. The problem is that it prints it as follows:**

> 'MIME-Version: 1.0\r\nDate: Wed, 6 Feb 2019 15:22:04
>   +0200\r\nMessage-ID: CAES-+zqJ-zFh40JBvB3bbkX-Md0dFQ-dc1ECQMynj-yp8C5eg@mail.gmail.com>\r\nSubject:
>   test\r\nFrom: Ops \r\nTo: test
>   \r\nContent-Type: multipart/alternative;
>   boundary="000000000000a56dd00581399c31"\r\n\r\n--000000000000a56dd00581399c31\r\nContent-Type:
>   text/plain;
>   charset="UTF-8"\r\n\r\ngoogle.com\r\n\r\n56.36.36.36\r\n\r\n--000000000000a56dd00581399c31\r\nContent-Type:
>   text/html; charset="UTF-8"\r\n\r\ngoogle.com
> 56.36.36.36\r\n\r\n--000000000000a56dd00581399c31--'

**I'm trying to print the mail as the original headers:**

> MIME-Version: 1.0
>
> Date: Wed, 6 Feb 2019 15:17:44 +0200
>
> Message-ID:
>
> Subject: test
>
> From: Test
>
> To: Test
>
> Content-Type: multipart/alternative;
>   boundary="00000000000020527b0581398d0e"
>
> --00000000000020527b0581398d0e
>
> Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"
>
> 156.36.32.32
>
> test.com
>
> --00000000000020527b0581398d0e
>
> Content-Type: text/html; charset="UTF-8"
>
> 156.36.32.32
> test.com
>
> --00000000000020527b0581398d0e--

**The script:**

```
import imaplib
import pprint

imap_host = 'imap.gmail.com'
imap_user = 'user@gmail.com'
imap_pass = 'password'

# connect to host using SSL
imap = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL(imap_host)

## login to server
imap.login(imap_user, imap_pass)

imap.select('Inbox')

tmp, data = imap.search(None, 'ALL')
for num in data[0].split():
        tmp, data = imap.fetch(num, '(RFC822)')
        pprint.pprint(data[0][1])
        imap.store(num, '+FLAGS', '\\Deleted')
    break
```

Comment: The thing you call "original headers" is more messed up than the raw string you are trying to convert from.

Comment: @tripleee Sorry edited my question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can easily see, the `pprint` representation has `\r\n` to represent a physical carriage return + line feed.  To split it into a sequence of lines,

```
message = data[0][1].split('\r\n')
```

To properly manipulate the resulting MIME message, you will probably want to parse it into an [`email.message`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html) and take it from there.

But the immediate fix is to not use `pprint` if you don't like what it does.

Comment: Using print message I get this result :  

['MIME-Version: 1.0', 'Date: Wed, 6 Feb 2019 16:02:04 +0200', 'Message-ID: <CAES-+zrUB17M37J-eHG8DdWjyqexD9myoOTg63PBoDA@mail.gmail.com>', 'Subject: fdf', 'From: ZecInt Ops <zesffit@gmail.com>', 'To:  Ops <int@gmail.com>', 'Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="000000000000b74c9105813a2b7d"', '', '--000000000000b74c9105813a2b7d', 'Content-Type: text/plain; charset="UTF-8"', '', 'okj.com', '', '--000000000000b74c9105813a2b7d', 'Content-Type: text/html; ', '', '--000000000000b74c9105813a2b7d--']

Comment: Just `print(data[0][1])` if that's all you care about (though watch out for those pesky Windows carriage returns)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`email.message`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/email.message.html) for a better representation of an email message (headers included)